# Does Type.GetProperties() guarantee a certain order for the PropertyInfo[] result?

Tags: c#, reflection

Does Type.GetProperties() guarantee a certain order for its PropertyInfo[] result? Such as returning them in alphabetical order by property name or the order they appear in code. Or is the order undefined?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx):

> The GetProperties method does not
>   return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or
>   declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which
>   properties are returned, because that
>   order varies.

Comment: Doh! I must have skimmed over that part. Note to self: wait a day before posting my stupid question. :)

Comment: It does seem to be consistent though. I have a test application that uses GetProperties to define and populate a DataGridView and the types and values the separate calls return always match.

Comment: @ChrisF: Are they in some arbitrary order or is there a pattern? If anything I thought they would be in the order they appeared in the code.

Comment: I would think that the order depends on the order they appear in the assembly; however, since the order they appear in the assembly can change from one build to another (depending on changes to the code), MSDN is telling you (sagely) don't count on a fixed order.

Comment: Doh, we needed order the way it is declared in code. No harm for .NET .GetProperty to follow that order at least, as I loop through return proeprties and export in .text file to again export it in SQL-DB using BCP, but no certain order is pain.

Comment: The same applies to GetFields order. In fact, GetFields order tends to change after a few calls to SetFields function. So the fields that are most frequently changed using the SetFields method might come first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can sort the array again using "PropertyInfo.MetadataToken" Like this :

```
Array.Sort(propertyInfos, delegate(PropertyInfo first, PropertyInfo second)
  {
            return first.MetadataToken.CompareTo(second.MetadataToken);
  });
```